# Multivariate number generation with pairwise correlation

Tags: regression, correlation, covariance, random-generation

I am trying to simulate some data for linear regression, where `p = 30`. The pairwise correlations are given, `0.85`. I am using R package `mvtnorm`, with `rmvnorm(length, mean, sigma)`. However this is using covariance instead of correlation, and the random matrix I simulated has a different correlation (and even covariance) from what I set up.

Can some one tell me why this happened, and how can I generate data with pairwise correlations?

Comment: Please include a minimal example that demonstrates it doesn't work.

Comment: This seems to work:     sigma=toeplitz(c(1,rep(0.85,29)));tmp=rmvnorm(n=200, mean = rep(0, nrow(sigma)), sigma = sigma)           ;cor(tmp[,5],tmp[,30])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The covariance is the same as correlation when the variances are 1.  Thus we can generate a sigma matrix as follows with the pairwise correlations equal to 1:

```
sigma=toeplitz(c(1,rep(0.85,29)))
```

Note i'm using 29 as you asked for `p=30`. Then we can simulate any length of data from this sigma matrix using `rmvnorm`:

```
set.seed(1) # to be reproducible
data=rmvnorm(n=200,sigma=sigma)
```

The default mean is 0 for each dimension so I haven't included it in the above.  You can then check the correlation of individual pairs as follows:

```
cor(data[,1],data[,5]);
```

Or you can get the correlation matrix:

```
cor(data);
```

You can see that most of them are around 0.85 ish.  You can make it more readable doing:

```
round(cor(data),2);
```

Comment: Thanks @adunaic! I used the corrplot((cor(data)) to visualise the correlation. I tried with n = 100 and 500, then I found when the size is small (100) the correlations are quite different - and color on the plot indicating correlation are different (apart from diagonal). Then as the size increases, pairwise correlation tend to be more similar around 0.85. How would sample size affect correlation when size is small? Thanks for inspiring me!

Comment: Correlation is taken as a sum of all pairs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) so if there are more pairs then you are likely to get closer to the true correlation structure.  As with almost all statistics, the larger your n the smaller your variance and hence the closer you are to the true value (if unbiased estimator).

Comment: If i've answered your question, please denote my answer as the correct answer and give it an up vote.